# Linq Group By Object Then Select

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking to group records by their `LeagueId` and `Date`. Then order desc on the date and then select the first occurrence of a distinct `LeagueId`. So far I have something like this but I don't know how to select stats in the first occurrence of a distinct `LeagueId`.

```
var stats =
    _statsRepository.FindBy(x => x.Active)
         .GroupBy(x => new { x.LeagueId, x.Date })
         .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.Date)
         .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Its pretty much a way to get the most recent stats per league. So League 1 = 12/02/2017 and league 2 could be 02/02/17. <--- disregard this, may be misleading.

There are many stat records that occur on a date in a league. So for a certain date with each league there would be multiple stats.

```
Record 1:
09/01/14,
Jim,
4 Goals,
League 1

Record 2:
13/01/14,
Jack,
2 Goals,
League 1

Record 3:
13/01/14,
James,
2 Goals,
League 1

Record 4:
15/01/14,
Hannah,
2 Goals,
League 2

Record 5:
15/01/14,
Harmony,
1 Goal,
League 2

Record 6:
10/01/14,
Alision,
3 Goals,
League 2
```

The records that should be selected are

```
Record 2:
13/01/14,
Jack,
2 Goals,
League 1

Record 3:
13/01/14,
James,
2 Goals,
League 1

Record 4:
15/01/14,
Hannah,
2 Goals,
League 2

Record 5:
15/01/14,
Harmony,
1 Goal,
League 2
```

**Explanation**: For league 1 Records 2 & 3 occurs later than record 1 so they are both selected. For league 2 records 4 & 5 should be selected as they are the latest date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the latest update, you need to group by `LeagueId` and simply get all the records from each grouping with `Date` equals max `Date` in the grouping:

```
var stats = _statsRepository.FindBy(x => x.Active)
    .GroupBy(x => x.LeagueId)  
    .SelectMany(g => g.Where(x => x.Date == g.Max(y => y.Date));
```

Another way to get the same result is to use `!Any` (SQL `NOT EXISTS`) construct:

```
var baseStats = _statsRepository.FindBy(x => x.Active);
var stats = baseStats
    .Where(x => !baseStats.Any(y => y.LeagueId == x.LeagueId && y.Date > x.Date));
```

I assume you work with `IQueryable`s (i.e. **not** *LINQ to Objects* where such things matter), so no optimizations like intermediate `Select`s are needed.

Comment: We don't know if the question is at its final state ;o) - but that looks fine for the current state

Comment: @SirRufo We never know for sure :)

Comment: Im sorry for not being clear the first few times. But yes this solves my problem very elegantly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You want to group by league then take the most recent date in the group for each league

```
var stats = _statsRepository.FindBy(x => x.Active)
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.LeagueId, x.Date })
            .GroupBy(g => g.Key.LeagueId)
            .Select(gg => new { LeagueId = gg.Key, Stats = gg.OrderByDescending(g => g.Key.Date).First().ToList() })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I want the whole stats records and not just the leagueid and date.

Comment: Then just remove the Select part after the OrderByDescending and return that First element

Comment: Select( x => x.OrderByDescending( y => y.Date ).First()

Comment: I had to use FirstOrDefault() as it was throwing an error with just First(). This returns the correct dates for the leagues but only one stat record per league when there is numerous records.

Comment: @BadDub  clarify completely what it is you want. The answer so far have been bars on what you asked. However you update that request with each modification based on what you asked. Provide a [mcve] including sample input and desired output

Comment: @SirRufo I have updated the OP. Sorry for the inconvenience so far. Hope the data makes sense and clears things up.

Comment: @BadDub check update to answer based on latest update to OP